# How do I remove parts of paths in a 2D vector grid?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, 2d-vector

I've really been struggling with this project. So I have a "grid" aka a 2D char vector. 79 chars wide, 20 chars high. I created a few functions that essentially draw paths from one edge of the grid to another. These "paths" are somewhat random.. where I have a random generator choose an int from 0-7 and uses a combo of the paths I made functions for. So.. Theres several paths/lines going through the grid.

The next part was to place rectangles/squares over these paths on the grid. After many hours of frustration, I got the program to place these rectangles over the paths.

This next part has me lost and I have no idea how to begin. I now need to determine if the paths somehow connect all of the rectangles together, but only 1 or 2 paths may connect to a rectangle. So if one of the rectangles does not touch a path, I need to call the function to regenerate a new grid with the paths and rectangles.

On top of being able to check if a path touches a rectangle in 1 or 2 places.. I need to remove excess path chars. So if the path doesn't connect to another rectangle or a path that is needed, I need to remove that char.

'#' are the paths and the '.' are the rectangles
Heres an example of what my program displays now:

```
        #                  #                                                   
        #                  #                                                   
   ........                #         ##############                            
   ........                #         #            # ..........                 
   ........                #         #            ##..........############     
   ........###########     #         #              ..........           #     
###........###########################              ..........           #     
   ........          #     #                        ..........           #     
   ........          #################################                   #     
                     #     #                         #                   #     
                     #     #                         #                   #     
            ........ #     #                         #                   #     
            ........ #     #                      ########################     
            ........ #     #######                #  ........                  
            ........ #           #                #  ........                  
############........##           #                #  ........                  
            ........             ##################  ........##################
            ........                                 ........                  
            ........                                 ........
```

Notice the extra '#' marks and how some of them are useless? Technically I don't have to remove where paths fork and reconnect with a path. I can technically have them touching in more than 1 place as I will be adding borders to the rectangles.. with only 1 or 2 spots that directly connect the '#' to '.' (not worried about that right now)They just can't be more than 1 '#' thick and the previous requirements. This is kind of what it should look like after I somehow figure out how to remove the ones I don't need:

```
 ........                          ##############                            
 ........                          #            # ..........                 
 ........                          #            ##..........     
 ........###########               #              ..........                
 ........          #################              ..........                
 ........          #     #                        ..........                
 ........          #################################                        
                   #     #                         #                        
                   #     #                         #                        
          ........ #     #                         #                        
          ........ #     #                      ####     
          ........ #     #######                #  ........                  
          ........ #           #                #  ........                  
          ........##           #                #  ........                  
          ........             ##################  ........
          ........                                 ........                  
          ........                                 ........
```

The closest i've gotten is detecting which direction a path goes from a certain spot.. But I have no idea how to use that to my methods of removing the '#' or checking for island rectangles.

Please help me :( I have no idea how to do this! Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you are asking for but I think it can go a long way to helping you, [What are some ideal algorithms for Rogue-like 2D dungeon generation?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2663/what-are-some-ideal-algorithms-for-rogue-like-2d-dungeon-generation), [Dungeon Generation](http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm:dungeon-generation) and this one [Dungeon-Building Algorithm](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Dungeon-Building_Algorithm) even has C++ code example. Also there is code to `rouge-like` games that must do the same thing as well.

Comment: Yeah that's essentially what we're making for this project. I can't seem to find a guide/tutorial for this specific part though =/ I should've began falling a tutorial at least for the dungeon generating. We have fairly specific functions and such that we're supposed to implement though

Comment: @ModdedLife Hopefully this at least gives you some good ideas and code to leverage. There is an amazing wealth of info on rouge-like games out there, who knew?

Comment: Yeah I did some research at the beginning of this project. Most of them are much more in-depth than what we're required to do though. It definitely helps though.